# Как тестировать зависящую от поддомена логику в режиме локальной разработки на NodeJS?

Tags: node.js, поддомены

Допустим, `https://example_institue.edu` - официальный сайт какого-то университета, а `https://bioengineering.example_institue.edu` - официальный сайт кафедры биоинженерии этого университета. По-хорошему каждый из этих сайтов должен обслуживать отдельный сервер (хотя бы виртуальный), тем не менее я бы хотел рассмотреть случай, когда оба сайта обслуживают один сервер и одно приложение.

В данном случае в зависимости от поддомена потребуется разный роутинг. Например, `https://example_institue.edu/about` - это страница информации об университете в целом, а `https://bioengineering.example_institue.edu/about` - это страница информации о кафедре биоинженерии, поэтому если роутеру указать просто `/about`, то он не сможет понять, какая именно страница нужна.

В принципе, для продакшена алгоритм ясен: нужно посмотреть поле `origin` в заголовках запроса и в зависимости от поддомена выбрать роутинг, объявленный тем или способом. Но как отладить этот механизм в режиме локальной разработки, где `origin` будет `http://localhost:3000/`?

Чтобы Вам в ответе не приходилось писать с нуля, приведу листинг Hello world на NodeJS с HTTP-модулем:

```js
import HTTP from "http";

const HOST = "123.4.5.6";
const PORT = 1337;

HTTP.createServer(requestListener).listen(PORT, HOST, () => {
  console.log({
    title: "Сервер запущен",
    description: `Ожидание запросов на хост：${HOST}, порт: ${PORT}...`
  });
  // В реальном приложении тут будет анализ запроса и выбор роутинга
});
```

Прошу в данном вопросе не рекомендовать никаких фреймворков типа `express`, потому что в данном вопросе идёт речь о решении задачи нативными средствами.

Comment: явно передавать в запросе заголовок HOST. или вообще, в то, что делает запросы, добавить интерсептор, добавляющий заголовок HOST

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для начала опишем сервер

server.js

```js
const http = require('http');

const hostname = '0.0.0.0';
const port = 8000;

const server = http.createServer((req, res) => {
  console.log("Request for: " + req.headers["host"]);
  res.statusCode = 200;
  res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'text/plain');
  res.end('Hello World');
});

server.listen(port, hostname, () => {
  console.log(`Server running at http://${hostname}:${port}/`);
});
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "docker_web_app",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Node.js on Docker",
  "author": "First Last",
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  }
}
```

Я запускал все в докере.

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:latest
WORKDIR /home/node/app
COPY source/ ./
RUN npm install
EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

docker-compose.yml

```yaml
version: "3.7"

services:
  node:
    build: .
    volumes:
      - "./source:/home/node/app"
    ports:
      - "127.0.0.1:8000:8000"
```

tree

```
~/DockerProjects/NodeJS ⌚ 11:52:17
$ tree
.
├── docker-compose.yml
├── Dockerfile
└── source
    ├── package.json
    └── server.js

1 directory, 4 files
```

Запускаем сервер

```
~/DockerProjects/NodeJS ⌚ 11:48:42
$ dc up                                           
Building with native build. Learn about native build in Compose here: https://docs.docker.com/go/compose-native-build/
Starting nodejs_node_1 ... done
Attaching to nodejs_node_1
node_1  | 
node_1  | > docker_web_app@1.0.0 start
node_1  | > node server.js
node_1  | 
node_1  | Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
```

Запросы

```
~ ⌚ 11:48:40
$ curl -i -H "HOST: test.com" http://127.0.0.1:8000
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 08:49:53 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Content-Length: 11

Hello World%                                                                                             
~ ⌚ 11:49:53
$ curl -i http://127.0.0.1:8000 
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: text/plain
Date: Mon, 19 Jul 2021 08:49:58 GMT
Connection: keep-alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5
Content-Length: 11

Hello World%                                                                                             
~ ⌚ 11:49:58
$
```

результат

```
node_1  | Server running at http://0.0.0.0:8000/
node_1  | Request for: test.com
node_1  | Request for: 127.0.0.1:8000
```

Думаю, все достаточно просто. Заголовок Host клиент обязан указать для HTTP протокола версии 1.1 и выше. А заголовок Origin указывается клиентом только при кросс-доменном запросе (CORS). И указывает не на тот домен К которому выполняется запрос, а на тот ОТ которого он пришел.

Comment: Благодарю Вас за ответ и в особенности за пример!

Answer (score 0):

Нужно поставить порт 80, а после в файле C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts прописать `127.0.0.1 example_institue.edu` и так каждый домен с новой строчки. Таким образом можно использовать адреса для теста.